# "self is not defined" mientras se accesa dentro de un loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Buenas y gracias por tomarse el tiempo por leer el post.

En el siguiente codigo obtengo el problema que se menciona en el titulo "self is not defined", pero si accedo al metodo fuera del loop, entonces, el metodo si es accesible

```
class A1:
    def f(self):
        print("abc")

    def g(self):
        print(self.f())

    def h():
        for letra in "ejemplo":
            f()
```

Puedo acceder al metodo "f" desde "g" mas sin embargo no puedo acceder a este desde "h" siendo la unica diferencia que este este dentgro de un for

Comment: Cuando llamas al método de una clase esa pasa por defecto un argumento que por convención se le llamó `self` si no especificas ese argumento no podrás usarlo, todo eso si el código pertenece a una clase. Si el código es así como está pues es por que dentro del scope de la función no has definido la variable `self` listo.

Comment: `self` significa o representa a una entidad a la cual la [función] o **método** forma parte. Esa entidad generalmente es una clase. Sin embargo es convención, `self` puede ser una variable de función normal. Pero, ¿Esas funciones `f` y `g` están dentro de una clase? ¿Por qué llamas `self.f()` desde una función `h()` que no tiene `self` como primer argumento?

Comment: Efectivamente esta dentro de la misma clase, ahora edito el codigo que aparece en el post. Ahora bien h() no se emplea en si dentro de la misma clase, por eso es que no tiene le puse self como primer argumento.

Answer (score 0):

Te faltó el `self` definirlo en el método `h`

```
def h(self):
    for letra in "ejemplo":
        self.f()
```

Answer (score 0):

Si `h()` forma parte de la clase, entonces debe llevar el identificador `self`, y cuando se va a llamar a un método de la misma clase, también se usa `self.el_nombre_del_metodo()`

Excepción sería cuando se usa un método estático, el cual está dentro de la clase, pero [*no forma parte de ella*].

```
class A1:

    def f(self):
        print("abc")

    def g(self):
        print(self.f())

    def h(self):
        for letra in "ejemplo":
            self.f()
            
    @staticmethod
    def m():
        for _ in range(3):
            A1().g()
```

Se puede crear una instancia para llamar al método h()

```
obj = A1()
obj.h()
# Imprime "abc" "abc" "abc" ... 7 veces (una por cada letra de "ejemplo")
```

En algunos lenguajes no es permitido, pero en Python se puede llamar a un método directamente sin instanciar. No te acostumbres a hacerlo:

```
A1().h()
# Imprime lo mismo que lo anterior.
```

En el caso del método estático, este no entiende el identificador `self`, por lo que necesita el nombre de la propia clase para acceder a ella. Su uso más típico es crear una librería de herramientas o utilidades dentro de la propia clase, por ejemplo: convertidor de formato, lectura y escritura simple de archivos, etc.
No es usual que los métodos estáticos se usen para interactuar con los otros métodos de la clase, de ser así entonces declararlo como método normal, sin embargo es posible, tal como está en el ejemplo.

Para acceder al método estático:

```
A1.m()
```

El resultado es:

```
abc
None
abc
None
abc
None
```

El `None` es porque `g()` tiene un `print()` que está esperando el resultado que devuelve `f()`. Pero `f()` no tiene ningún `return`, así que Python lo interpreta como `None`. Para arreglarlo simplemente quita ese `print()` y déjalo como `self.f()`.